# Merging multiple pandas dataframes without duplicating columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large class of students separated into sections with each student havinga unique ID. I have the entire roster stored in a dataframe. I also have multiple dataframes representing the grades from a particular section of students on a particular assignment. I would like to merge all of this information into a single dataframe that represents my gradebook. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize roster
data = [['ab10', 'Ann Big'], ['ca9', 'Carl Ahn'], ['jb19', 'John Brown'], ['cf25', 'Carol Fox']]
roster = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name'])

# Initialize the section grades
data = [['ab10', 95], ['ca9', 72]]
grades0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Exp1'])

data = [['ab10', 83], ['ca9', 97]]
grades1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Exp2'])

data = [['jb19', 61], ['cf25', 95]]
grades2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Exp1'])

# Now merge the section grades with the roster to generate final gradebook
roster = roster.merge(grades0, on = 'ID', how = 'outer')
roster = roster.merge(grades1, on = 'ID', how = 'outer')
roster = roster.merge(grades2, on = 'ID', how = 'outer')

print(roster)
```

This code generates the following:

```
     ID        Name  Exp1_x  Exp2  Exp1_y
0  ab10     Ann Big    95.0  83.0     NaN
1   ca9    Carl Ahn    72.0  97.0     NaN
2  jb19  John Brown     NaN   NaN    61.0
3  cf25   Carol Fox     NaN   NaN    95.0
```

I don't want the duplicated Exp1 columns with the suffixes _x and _y. Instead I want:

```
     ID        Name    Exp1  Exp2
0  ab10     Ann Big    95.0  83.0 
1   ca9    Carl Ahn    72.0  97.0
2  jb19  John Brown    61.0   NaN
3  cf25   Carol Fox    95.0   NaN
```

There should be no duplicated data between the grade dataframes (but it would be good practice to raise an error were an overlap to exist).

Answer (score 3):

#### `reduce` with `combine_first`

As there are is no duplication between the grades dataframes, we can therefore `reduce` with `combine_first` to combine all the the dataframes together

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(pd.DataFrame.combine_first, 
      [g.set_index('ID') for g in (roster, grades0, grades1, grades2)])
```

---

```
      Exp1  Exp2        Name
ID                          
ab10  95.0  83.0     Ann Big
ca9   72.0  97.0    Carl Ahn
cf25  95.0   NaN   Carol Fox
jb19  61.0   NaN  John Brown
```

Comment: combine_first is exactly what I needed! Many thanks.

Comment: @Melissa Pleased to help!

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy using `pd.concat()` with `.groupby()` for these cases, not only I believe might result cleaner, but you save a couple of lines of code and probably efficiency too (as you won't be making multiple merges). Replace your merge lines with:

```
roster = pd.concat([roster,grades0,grades1,grades2]).groupby(['ID'])['Exp1','Exp2'].sum().merge(roster,on='ID')
print(roster)
```

Which outputs:

```
    ID  Exp1  Exp2        Name
0  ab10  95.0  83.0     Ann Big
1   ca9  72.0  97.0    Carl Ahn
2  cf25  95.0   0.0   Carol Fox
3  jb19  61.0   0.0  John Brown
```

You can then re-order the columns to your preferred order. And if you prefer having `NaNs` to 0s then you can add `.replace(0,np.nan)` after the `merge()`.

```
     ID  Exp1  Exp2        Name
0  ab10  95.0  83.0     Ann Big
1   ca9  72.0  97.0    Carl Ahn
2  cf25  95.0   NaN   Carol Fox
3  jb19  61.0   NaN  John Brown
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I do not know the names of the assignments a priori? I need to avoid hardcoding ['Exp1','Exp2'].